# AWS4 Signer cannot be instantiated after upgrading library

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

So, i previously upgrade AGP from `7.4.2` into `8.2.2`, and `Kotlin Gradle Plugin` from `1.6.21` into `1.9.22` alongside with `KTX` from `1.8.0` into `1.12.0`. But after that, `Koin` cannot instantiate the AWS.

Here's the error message that happened after update:

> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer> cannot be instantiated at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

Here is the rule previously when everything works fine:

```
##### AWS ######
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**               { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.QueueUrlHandler  { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.transform.sax.*     { public *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.**           { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.model.*Exception* { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.**                             { *; }
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*

-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.impl.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.conn.scheme.**
```